# How to split in an array list and get the correct output?

Tags: java, arraylist

Code a method called `countStudentsPerFaculty` that accepts a string as input represents a faculty name and returns an integer value that represents the number of students in that faculty.

For example:

If the enrollment ArrayList has `[“John|FIT”,”Tim|Law”,”Emma|FIT”]`

```
Input “FIT”
return 2,
Input “Law”
return 1,
Input “Business”
return 0
```

I'm a beginner in Java. I've already used the .split() method to split the String in the array. But I'm not getting the output I want.

```java
public int countStudentsPerFaculty(String facultyName) {
    int numberOfStudents = 0;

    for (String elem: enrollment) {
        String[] nameOfFaculty = elem.split("|");
        numberOfStudents++;
    }
    return numberOfStudents;
}
```

This is my code. My code is returning the output for each faculty as 3. Where am I going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start by writing what is in the array, instead of doing this : elem.split("|"); write out the elem instead. It looks as your List contains 3 strings. You are not counting inside the splits after. You are simply counting the times you iterate over the strings

Comment: You're never checking any names here, `nameOfFaculty` is never used. So you're just getting the list size as output.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that if nameOfFaculty is equal to facultyName(method argument) then add one to numberOfStudents. same as below :

```
public int countStudentsPerFaculty(String facultyName) {
        int numberOfStudents = 0;

        for (String elem: enrollment) {
            String nameOfFaculty = elem.split("\\|")[1];
            if(nameOfFaculty.equals(facultyName))
                numberOfStudents++;
        }
        return numberOfStudents;
    }
```

Comment: The `|` should be escaped, i.e. `elem.split("\\|")`. Or just use `if(elem.endsWith(facultyName))` then you don't need to split the strings

Answer (score 0):

When you call `String.split(String regex)`, you get a array of Strings. For example, if I take the first String, `"John|FIT"`, it will return an array: `{"John", "FIT"}`. You arent carrying any operation on the array of String, you get, so the for loop is basically useless. All you are doing is getting the number of elements in the array, by incrementing the value of `numberOfStudents` by 1, each time you iterate over the Strings in the array. Since there are 3 Strings in your array, `countStudentsPerFaculty` returns 3. `@Zahra`'s answer gives the correct code, but I think it is important to clarify the working.

---

Lets take the same String as an example: `"John|FIT"`.
The first statement of the for loop takes the second String in the array `{"John", "FIT"}`. the if statement checks whether the name of the faculty, `"FIT"` in this case is equal to the parameter of the method. If so, `numberOfStudents` is incremented by one. This procedure takes place for all the Strings in enrollment.
For better clarity, you can copy `@Zahra`'s code, and try to debug it....

---

Also, as specified by `@Eritrean`, the split() method's parameter("|"), should be escaped with 2 backslashes ("\\|") as it accepts a regex String, as "|" is a special regex.